# Recycler view android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

Whenever a change a value in the onbind function of my adapter, a new item is added

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.postItemTitle.text= items[position].title
    var post:Post=items[position]
    val user_id=1
    var user_liked=post.users_liked
    if(user_liked.contains(user_id)){
        post.liked=true
    }
    if(post.liked){
        holder.postLikeBtn.setImageDrawable(context.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.likered))
        holder.postLikes.text=(post.likes).toString()
    }
    else{
        holder.postLikes.text=(post.likes).toString()
    }
    holder.postLikeBtn.setOnClickListener {
        if(post.liked){
            //change color of like btn
//                holder.postLikeBtn.setImageDrawable(context.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.likebtn))
                //set post as unliked
                post.liked=false
                //remove user from list of users that liked post
                user_liked.remove(user_id)
                //update the database
                var likes=post.likes--
                holder.postLikes.text=(likes).toString()
                val ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("post")
                ref.child(post.key).setValue(post)
            }
            else{
                //update post that u liked
                post.liked=true
                user_liked.add(user_id)
                //make button red
                holder.postLikeBtn.setImageDrawable(context.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.likered))
                //increase no of likes
                var likes=post.likes++
                holder.postLikes.text=(likes).toString()
                items[position]=post
                //update database

            val ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("post")
            ref.child(post.key).setValue(post)
        }
        items[position]=post
        this.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

Comment: `override fun onBindViewHolder`? You mean `@Override public void onBindViewHolder`, right?

Comment: it's kotlin, mate

Comment: `onBindViewHolder` is called every time when the view is going to be displayed by `layoutManager` `onCreateViewHolder` is called once so adapt the code that the view's initialisation is within the view class and not in the `adapter` you can have callbacks or interfaces within the adapter and view to facilitate that. Also if it's just the item at `position` being changed why not use `notifyItemChanged` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it, actually, totally wrong. Here's an [article](https://medium.com/androidsolutions/recyclerview-adapters-4d39a24da3c0) how to handle RecyclerView.

Basically, you don't handle any ui/data inside `onBindViewHolder`, it's dedicated to pass data to your actual class, which extends from `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` and overrides `bind` method. See the article for more details.